# State machine diagram: how to tell that one transition induces another?

Tags: audio, uml, real-time, aggregate-functions, state-machine

I have a class aggregating sound in real time. Aggreation means it calculates sound parameters like mean amplitude, noise level and so on for a time units, longer than sound frames. Frames are PCM and last less than millisecond, while aggregation units are 1/10 of second and longer.

I wish to draw UML state machine diagram of this class.

It consists of two smaller state diagrams, one tracking frames, other tracking aggregation units, by cycles. If first diagram detects full frame received, it should kick second diagram, where frame is processed and aggreagation data for one unit is updated.

I drew the picture below.

My question is: how to draw that first machine transition from full frame state to initial state initiates of induces the transition in the second machine?

I entitled question transition on second diagram as "frame".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you need is that the first machine sends an event to the second when `Full frame received` is entered. There are several ways to do it. You could add an effect on the transition leading to `Full frame received`, or, you could also define an "entry action" for  `Full frame received`.

Once you send an event upon entering `Full frame received`, you can define in the second state machine a transition reacting to it.

In the [UML Spec. 2.4.1](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/), "entry action" is described on page 561, `effect` of transitions on page 581.